# Updating nested D3 angular directive with data

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I have the following D3 directive components:

1. pieChart - basic pie chart
2. barChart - basic bar chart

Each directive looks like so:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('secure').directive('pieChart', [
        'd3', function(d3) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    data: "="
                },
                templateUrl: '/Angular/Shared/GraphChart/pieChart.html',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    // setup the d3 chart

                    scope.render = function(data) {
                       // apply data to chart and transform
                    }

                    scope.$watch('data', function(data) {
                        // Watch for scope changes and push new data
                        scope.render(data);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
})();
```

Both are consumed inside of another directive, called `collector`, like show below. There can be *N* number of collectors. As you can see all collectors and chart data per collector is in the `collectors` array on `collector` directive's scope.

```
<div ng-repeat="collector in collectors">
    <div class="collector">
        <div class="bars">
           <div bar-chart data="collector.acceptor"></div>
        </div>
        <div pie-chart data="collector.denomSegments"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, i have a socket connection that pushes updates from the server (new collectors array) to the `collector` directive, which in turn updates all charts in the ng-repeat.

However, what's happening is any time `scope.collectors` array changes in the `collector` directive's scope, all charts directives are forced to redraw in the ng-repeat. So, the $watch inside of each chart directive becomes completely useless as it never executes without the entire `link` function executing along with it and, of course, redrawing the entire chart instead of merely updating it.

I hope this makes sense. I'm not sure if there is a way to fix it. The only thing i can think of is to use the collectors array on the `collector` directive to initialize all charts on initial page load and then have each chart component `$watch` on a `$rootScope` variable for updates to the chart. This way I completely bypass the parent collector directive from rebinding all charts. But this seems very complicated because i'd have to make sure that the right chart gets the right update from `$rootScope`.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to use `track by ...` in your ng-repeat? I think the problem could be that arriving data looks totally different to Angular and so the `ng-repeat` creates new elements instead of updating existing ones.

Comment: @hgoebl, that did fix it! Still very new to angular, but loving these minute details. Could you post this as your answer? I'll go ahead and accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. If you like you can answer your own question, because you have all the code and the effective change. I'd upvote that :-)